# How to change MsgBox button language

Tags: vb.net, culture, msgbox

I understand that the language of Message Box buttons is linked to the language of the Windows system.  But this may not be the language of the end user.  For instance, in a county like Switzerland having four official languages (German, French, Italian and Romansh), it is not unusual for a Windows system to be set up in English and not fit the user's needs.  Adjusting the Windows Regional and Language options does not affect the language of Message Box buttons.

Is there any way to dynamically set an application to respect the System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID instead of the system language?  I tried playing around with the parent form Localizable and Language settings with no success.

Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: one way to go around that issue would be to build your own MessageBox. Check for an example at https://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2006/01/A-custom-MessageBox.aspx

Comment: Merci Éric!  In searching for a solution, I saw a post from you dating back I think to 2003 which basically provides the same suggestion.  I was really kind'a hoping that such culture issues might have been addressed by Microsoft over the last 17 years.  This said, thanks for your input!  I will proceed on that basis.  Merci à nouveau!

Comment: The language would be CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, not CultureInfo.CurrentCulture (that's for the date/time formats etc). But of course setting that value does not change the buttons neither. I would not care too much though as we Swiss are used to all kind of buttons and understand but the basic dialog buttons in English and the other Swiss languages (alright, maybe not in Romansh). I don't think Microsoft can change these old APIs, they are in use in billions of programs, and if only 0.01% has a problem with the new behavior, that are still 100000s of applications...